# Validate SQL Query Integrity before Executing in VB6

Tags: sql, vb6

I have a MS Access 2003 Application to port to Visual Basic 6.0 currently. For this purpose, I have written a copy of the usual DLookup commonly used in Access.

Here is the code so far.

```
Public Function cDLookup(TargetField As String, TargetTable As String, cTCondition As String) As String
'Eigene Implementation von DLookup
Dim result As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String
On Error GoTo Fehlerbehandlung

'Zusammenbauen der Query
SQL = "SELECT " & TargetField & " FROM " & TargetTable & " WHERE " & cTCondition

Call dbConn
'Initiate Database connection object cn

rs.Open SQL, cn
If (rs.RecordCount = 1) Then
result = cleanString(rs.GetString)
Debug.Print ("[DLOOKUP] Erfolgreich Einen Datensatz gefunden und konvertiert. Output: " & result)

ElseIf (rs.RecordCount > 1) Then
result = "#ErrRC"
Debug.Print ("[DLOOKUP] Es wurden " & CStr(rs.RecordCount) & " Datensätze statt einem festgestellt. Dies ist nicht erlaubt")

Else
result = "#ErrGen"
Debug.Print ("[DLOOKUP] Es ist ein Fehler in der Abfrage aufgetreten")
End If
rs.Close

cDLookup = result
Exit Function
Fehlerbehandlung:
Debug.Print ("[DLOOKUP] Fehler im Ausführen der Prozedur cDLookup()]")
cDLookup = "#Fehler"
Exit Function
End Function
```

My main issue is with the generated Queries. If a user types garbage that gets inputted into this, there is a runtime error from ADODB when opening the recordset. Can I verify beforehand that a SQL query is not going to do that and catch it to not crash my entire program somehow?

Comment: No, not in the way you want. You need to just try to execute it, and handle the error gracefully. You could do something like create a function called "ValidateSQL" with its own error handler, try to execute it, and return false if the query failed. You could even pass the recordset in byref and set it to have the results if it passes.

Comment: Alright. Post that as an Answer please so I can accept it.

Comment: just curious, why port to vb6?

Comment: Its software handling requests and listens from Scanners via the standart serial comport. Currently 1/3 of the scanners use a .MDB Access 2003 file as endpoint, while 2/3 and all the new ones use a VB6 Application. Im tasked to port the older 1/3 over. The reason is unification and the need for it to run on everything from win95 to win7 seemlessly.

Comment: sounds like an unpleasant task! good luck!

Comment: Its largely only copy/paste work. A few things get unpleasant but otherwise its largely copy/paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *know* you're generating trash, why take the trash to the database and wait for the database to blow up to tell you it's trash? *Fail Fast* is a thing for a reason.

Hitting a database is not *free*. Even if it's relatively fast, it's orders of magnitude slower than plain code.

Don't get me wrong, I don't mean "validate that the specified field name does indeed exist in the table with the specified name" and "parse that where statement to see if it makes sense".

However, a few sanity-checks will cost much less than a useless trip to the database. You could:

- Verify that the table and field names either don't contain any spaces, or are enclosed in square brackets;
- Verify that the table and field names aren't empty;
- Verify that the WHERE clause doesn't start with "WHERE", and that it's not empty.

If these simple checks pass, *then* have the database blow up if they're still wrong.

Answer (score 3):

No, not in the way you want. You need to just try to execute it, and handle the error gracefully. You could do something like create a function called "ValidateSQL" with its own error handler, try to execute it, and return false if the query failed. You could even pass the recordset in byref and set it to have the results if it passes.

It's been a long time so forgive syntax mistakes. Something like this:

```
Function ValidateSQL(ByRef rs as ADODB.Recordset) as Boolean
On Error GoTo Hell
ValidateSQL = True

'open recordset here
Set rs = ....
If False Then
   Hell:
   ValidateSQL = False
End If
End Function
```